# Zend_Uri_Http: Invalid URI supplied - even though url is valid

Tags: zend-framework, url

i have a url similar to this

```
http://one/two/three:four&five=six|seven
```

also i have

```
Zend_Uri_Http::setConfig(array('allow_unwise' => true));
```

in order to be able to use "|". when i try to use

```
Zend_Http_Client::setUri()
```

on my url, i get

```
Zend_Uri_Exception: Invalid URI supplied
```

when i hit the url from the browser, it works. how to avoid this problem. any ideas are welcome

Answer (score 1):

The URL will be valid if you change it to:

```
http://one/two/three:four?five=six|seven
```

What is supposed to be the query string in that URI?  You have to separate the query string from the path by `?` before you can use `&` to separate arguments.

Answer (score 0):

so it turns out i had a rewrite rule, defined in my httpd-vhosts.conf file, which created valid url after my invalid url was hit. since i needed to hit the url from within the zend framework phpunit test, i applied rewrite rule manually and got the correct url

moral of the story, put all the relevant info into your question, or else, nobody will be able to help you out